# Java design pattern for two classes sharing identical and similar but different methods

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say my application has some services implemented as `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Both have some similarities but also differences.

1. Both classes have a `start()` method with the same method signature but a different implementation.
2. Both classes have a `process()` method with a different signature and a different implementation.
3. Both classes have an identical `log()` method, i.e. the code is exactly the same.

#### Class A

```
public class ClassA {

    public String start(String s1, String s2) {
        startImplementation();
        return someString;
    }

    public String process(String s) {
        processingImplementation();
        return processedString;
    }

    private String log(String s) {
        logImplementation();
        return sharedString;
    }
}
```

#### Class B

```
public class ClassB {

    public String start(String s1, String s2) {
        otherStartImplementation();
        return someString;
    }

    public String process(Long l) {
        otherProcessingImplementation();
        return processedString;
    }


    private String log(String s) {
        logImplementation();
        return sharedString;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble thinking of a "design pattern" how I could organize this in a more generic way. As of 3. I could easily move this method to a superclass which `ClassA` and `ClassB` extend. But how would/could I design the application so that 1. and 2. are also taken into account?

Item 1. sounds a little bit like an interface to me but I don't have any idea how this could be combined with the superclass for item 3. And what about item 2?

Comment: Of course you can only extract **common** behaviour to **common** super-classes. Extracting something that is **different** into a **common** class makes no sense, doesn´t it? So when your methods have different signatures and different impementation, they should not go to any common class. In short: extract what is common to both classes and leave the differences in the concrete implementations.

Comment: Maybe oan use generics for similar methods having different parameters. But that highly depends on what those methods actually do, so that´s just a guess. I doubt anyone here can give you a more concrete answer, because your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Implement adapters.

Comment: Worth asking: have you thought about making them the same class (like with one `start` renamed)? Are these really different types that have to be in different classes?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Without knowing how these classes are expected to be used, you cannot design it. When a caller calls e.g. `start()`, does it expect uniform semantics across A and B? What about the rest of the methods?

Comment: How are start, process and log methods related? How will clients use these classes? Are they expected to be used in similar use cases? It's entirely possible that both classes happen to accidentally have similar interfaces, while not being related at all. Is there cases where clients would like to treat A & B the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would design this so that `class A` and `class B` extend a generic abstract class, with a type parameter for the `process` method's parameter type.

```java
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
    public abstract String start(String s1, String s2);

    public abstract String process(T value);

    protected final String log(String s) {
        // shared log implementation
    }
}
```

```java
public class A extends BaseClass<String> {
    @Override
    public String start(String s1, String s2) {
        // A.start implementation
    }

    @Override
    public String process(String s) {
        // A.process implementation
    }
}
```

```java
public class B extends BaseClass<Long> {
    @Override
    public String start(String s1, String s2) {
        // B.start implementation
    }

    @Override
    public String process(Long l) {
        // B.process implementation
    }
}
```

In Java 9+, you could instead use a generic `public interface Base<T>` instead of an abstract class, by giving `log` a default implementation. However, that doesn't allow you to make `log` only accessible to the implementing classes, and it doesn't prevent subclasses from overriding `log`.

Comment: This solves OP's problem, but inheritance is fragile. You'll see if it holds up for a future `ClassC` if it needs to fit in. It's hard to predict the future, which is what inheritance implies.

Answer (score 2):

How about using composition over inheritance? The implementations of `start` and `process` could be provided by functions like in the example below:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

class X<T> {
    public String start(BiFunction<String, String, String> f, String s1, String s2) {
        return f.apply(s1, s2);
    }

    public String process(Function<T, String> f, T t) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }

    // example
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X<String> xString = new X();
        xString.start((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2, "a", "b");

        X<Long> xLong = new X();
        xLong.process((t) -> { Long tt = t * 2;return tt.toString(); }, 4L);
    }
}
```

Same as previous example, but with implementations provided in the constructor and using functional interfaces instead of lambdas.

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

class StartFunctionExample implements BiFunction<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1 + s2;
    }
}

class ProcessFunctionExample implements Function<Long, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Long t) {
        Long tt = (t * 2);
        return tt.toString();
    }
}

class Z<T> {
    private final BiFunction<String, String, String> startFunction;
    private final Function<T, String> processFunction;

    public Z(
            BiFunction<String, String, String> startFunction,
            Function<T, String> processFunction
    ) {
        this.startFunction = startFunction;
        this.processFunction = processFunction;
    }

    public String start(String s1, String s2) {
        return startFunction.apply(s1, s2);
    }

    public String process(T t) {
        return processFunction.apply(t);
    }

    // example
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Z<Long> xLong = new Z(new StartFunctionExample(), new ProcessFunctionExample());
        xLong.start("a", "b"); // ab
        xLong.process(7L);     // 14
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let a different class implement the logging, the processing can be done by classes implementing the service interface:

```
interface Processable {
  String start(String s1, String s2);
  process(String s);
}

class LogDecorator {

  private Processable p;

  public LogDecorator(Processable p) {
    this.p = p;
  }

  public String start(String s1, String s2) {
    p.start(s1, s2);
  }

  public String process(String s) {
    p.process();
  }

  protected final String log(String s) {
    // logging
  }

}
```